# enumerated list filtering out of sequence

Tags: python

I have an enumurated list like so.

input.txt:

```
hello
hi
hi
hi
hi
some 
text
here
hi
hi
```

Code:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as infile:
    infile_list = []
    for line in infile:
        infile_list.append(line)
    for i,t in enumerate(infile_list):
        if "hi" in line:
            print(i, t)
```

Output:

```
1 hi
2 hi
3 hi
4 hi
8 hi
9 hi
```

I want to loop through the list and print only numbers incl the text that are not in sequence(the list I wanna clean up is way bigger but same idea). So in this case I'd like to print 1 and 8 only.
I've been fiddling around with some if statements and loops but I'm too much of a newb to even conceptually get close.

Anyone point me in the right direction?
Thx!

EDIT: code added

EDIT: infile contents added

Comment: can you please show the `for` loop where the `i` and `t` come from?

Comment: Can you provide the full code?

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: This is still not a [MCVE],  we cannot reproduce your output. Please read [ask] and then add the said MCVE.

Comment: Your output should start with 0 because by default the first `enumerate` index is 0. Why does it start with 1?

Comment: Keep the line number i from the previous "hi" line in a variable j. If j - i > 1, update j and keep the line, else update j and discard the line.

Comment: should be good now?

Comment: Now you have an acceptable question! I'll look into it.

Comment: Mr.T, thats whats I'm looking for indeed. But I can't get my head around the how

Comment: @GwJones For future reference: If you want people to get a notification, you have to @ them. Exception is the thread owner, who gets automatically a notification.

Comment: @Mr.T can u please give me a sample code for your alternative? I'm breaking my head its starting to hurt

Comment: What's wrong with timgeb's nice itertools approach?

Comment: @Mr.T Nothing but I'm learning and the more alternatives the better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you asked me nicely. But I still prefer timgeb's version:

```
#read the file into a list
#line[:-1] removes the linebreak `\n` from the end of each line
infile_list = [line[:-1] for line in open("test.txt", "r")]
#initialise the flag
flag = False
#loop through all lines
for i, line in enumerate(infile_list):
    #test if "hi" is in line
    #if you want to check if it is at the beginning of the line, use line.startswith()
    if "hi" in line:
        #did the previous line contain a "hi"?
        if not flag:
            #no -> print line
            print(i, line) 
            #update flag
            flag = True
    else:
        #reset flag
        flag = False
```

You can follow the code execution on [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=infile_list%20%3D%20%5B'hello',%20'hi',%20'hi',%20'hi',%20'hi',%20'some%20',%20'text',%20'here',%20'hi',%20'hi'%5D%23initialise%20the%20flag%0Aflag%20%3D%20False%0A%23loop%20through%20all%20lines%0Afor%20i,%20line%20in%20enumerate%28infile_list%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%23test%20if%20%22hi%22%20is%20in%20line%0A%20%20%20%20%23if%20you%20want%20to%20check%20if%20it%20is%20at%20the%20beginning%20of%20the%20line,%20use%20line.startswith%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%22hi%22%20in%20line%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23did%20the%20previous%20line%20contain%20a%20%22hi%22%3F%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20not%20flag%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23no%20-%3E%20print%20line%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28i,%20line%29%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23update%20flag%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20flag%20%3D%20True%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23reset%20flag%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20flag%20%3D%20False&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt quite work. Since the previous line gets discarded however the line that follows doesn't so I get line 1, 3, etc.

Comment: @GwJones I wonder, why you get this output. I added a link to Python Tutor, where you can follow the code execution and see, what happens at each step with the variables. As expected, it only prints out the first line within each group.

Comment: Yes I made a mistake, put the else statement a level too deep. It works like a charm, many thanks! Also thx for the python tutor link. This is gonna help me in the future!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can iterate over the lines of `infile` directly, there's no need to append the lines to a list first. In my demo I'll be using a list as a fake file.

Most of the work is done by [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to find sequences of lines with `'hi'`. (Currently I'm checking whether the line, without leading or trailing whitespace, is equal to `'hi'`, but use whatever revised logic you need for the `key` argument.)

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> 
>>> infile = '''hello
... hi
... hi
... hi
... hi
... some 
... text
... here
... hi
... hi'''.splitlines()
>>> 
>>> numbered = enumerate(infile)
>>> grouper = groupby(numbered, key=lambda num_line: num_line[1].strip() == 'hi')
>>> result = [next(group) for hi, group in grouper if hi]
>>> 
>>> result
[(1, 'hi'), (8, 'hi')]
```

If you are confused what's going on here I encourage you to print out the intermediate results.

**edit**: demonstrating intermediate results

`numbered`

```
>>> numbered = list(numbered)
>>> numbered
[(0, 'hello'), (1, 'hi'), (2, 'hi'), (3, 'hi'), (4, 'hi'), (5, 'some '), (6, 'text'), (7, 'here'), (8, 'hi'), (9, 'hi')]
```

content of `grouper`

```
>>> grouper = groupby(numbered, key=lambda num_line: num_line[1].strip() == 'hi')
>>> [(hi, list(group)) for hi, group in grouper]
[(False, [(0, 'hello')]), (True, [(1, 'hi'), (2, 'hi'), (3, 'hi'), (4, 'hi')]), (False, [(5, 'some '), (6, 'text'), (7, 'here')]), (True, [(8, 'hi'), (9, 'hi')])]
```